# Using TODAY() in YYYY-MM-DD format with Conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

In Excel, is there a way to format TODAY() into the YYYY-MM-DD format? I've setup Conditional Formatting so that if a cell =TODAY(), the entire row becomes bold. However, it only works when the dates are in standard MM-DD-YYYY format. Any suggestions?

Current Conditional Formatting formula looks like this:

```
=$B1=TODAY()
```

*The date cells, which come from an external database are stored as YYYY-MM-DD in column 'B'.*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then one of two things.  Your date is text and not a true date, or there is a time component to your date that the format is hiding.

For the prior, text instead of date, use:

```
=$B1=TEXT(TODAY(),"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

But the better solution is to change the text to a date or remove the time part.  Either will be done with this formula:

```
=INT(--$B1) = TODAY()
```

Comment: @msklut then you "Dates" in column `B` are actually Text and one really should convert them to true dates.

Comment: I would, but they're stored as text in a MySQL database that I'm connected to in Excel.